# How to Serialise a model object into JSON String - Swift 3

Tags: ios, json

My model is

```
public class getCompanyRequestModel
{
    public var userLoginId : String?
    public var searchString : String?
    public var tableName : String?
}
```

in viewController's viewdidload method, i created object of getCompanyRequestModel

```
var objGetCompany = getCompanyRequestModel()

objGetCompany.userLoginId = "Dilip";
objGetCompany.searchString = "tata";
objGetCompany.tableName = "null";
```

now i wanna to get JSON string from objGetCompany same as below

```
"{\"UserLoginId\":\"Dilip\",\"SearchString\":\"tata\",\"TableName\":\"null\"}";
```

in C# i get the JSON String from below line of code

```
string JsonParameters =     JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objGetCompany);
```

Any one interested to solve my issue :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171791/how-to-convert-nsobject-class-object-into-json-in-swift

Comment: Current Duplicate is make array of object JSON array string you need to call this for single object and pass that dictionary to `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:)` to convert it `Data` and then convert data to string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a property `jsonRepresentation` to the class:

```
var jsonRepresentation : String {
    let dict = ["userLoginId" : userLoginId, "searchString" : searchString, "tableName" : tableName]
    let data =  try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [])
    return String(data:data, encoding:.utf8)!
}
```

By the way: Class names in Swift are supposed to start with a capital letter.

And don't use optionals as a laziness alibi not to write initializers...

Update:

In Swift 4 there is a smarter way: Remove `jsonRepresentation` and adopt `Codable`

```
public class CompanyRequestModel : Codable { ...
```

then use `JSONEncoder`

```
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(objGetCompany)
let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
```

Comment: Thanks vadian. It works properly.

Comment: how  can i get the JSON in a sequence because it gives response as below {"tableName":"null","userLoginId":"mahesh123","searchString":"tata"} whereas i wanna to in {"userLoginId":"mahesh123","searchString":"tata", "tableName":"null"}

Comment: A dictionary is unordered by definition. If you want a specific order use an array but then you will lose the key/value semantics.

Answer (score -1):

```
        let text = "{\"UserLoginId\":\"Dilip\",\"SearchString\":\"tata\",\"TableName\":\"null\"}";
        if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                let dictData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
                let company = getCompanyRequestModel()
                company.userLoginId = dictData["UserLoginId"] as? String
                company.searchString = dictData["SearchString"] as? String
                company.tableName = dictData["TableName"] as? String
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```