# Convert NSObject to JSON string

Tags: json, swift, nsobject

I have a class that conforms to NSObject and has fields like NSNumber and NSMutableArray, so cannot really use Codable here.

So the class is like this:

```
class Custom: NSObject {
    var users: NSMutableArray?
    var type: NSNumber?
    .. and many more fields
}
```

Now i have an object of this class and want to get JSON string from that object :

I have tried following :

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: customObject, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) as? [String: Any]

let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paymentData, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
```

The above two code gave crash like Invalid top-level type in JSON write'

`And used SwiftyJson library too but that too gave the error SwiftyJSON.SwiftyJSONError.unsupportedType`

I wanted to try Codable but that requires me to convert NSNumber to Int and MSMutableArray to Array but I cannot really change this as I have used this code in many other places and also my code is working with Objective C so either I had to use NSNumber or had to convert between Int and NSNumber too many times.

Is there a solution that doesn't require changing the current implementation of class and still convert the object to json. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not because you have an object that all properties are JSON supported type that it can be transformed into JSON like that. Because The Object is not a supporte type itself. If you don't want to use Codable, you need a method that transform `Custom` into a `Dictionary`.

Comment: @Larme Can you suggest some code how to achieve this, and how to get json after converting to dictionary

Comment: Do something like this: `func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] { return ["users": users ?? [], "type": type ?? something, etc]}`, then do `let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: customObject.toDictionary, options: [])` (by the way, as? [String: Any] wouldn't work at all since it'd be a `(NS)Data` object).

Comment: @Larme Will try this tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @Larme Although this didn't gave any error. I used lldb po command to print this json but couldn't. Is there a way to print this json to see how actually the data is formatted.

Comment: That's `(NS)Data` JSON. Use `String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)` if you want a "debug value".